# Verifying Statistical Independence

Tags: probability, random-variables

The question is to check whether x and y are independent if

1. $p(x,y) = \theta^2(1-\theta)^{x+y}$
2. $p(x,y) = \frac{e^{-2\lambda}\lambda^{x+y}}{x!y!}$

I can see tell that the 1) is a multiplication of two geometric distributions and 2) is two poissons, is that all we need combined with $p(x,y) = p_x(x)p_y(y)$ to show that X and Y are independent

Thanks

Comment: That's all. $\phantom{.}$

Comment: Hint: If $p(x,y) = p_x(x)p_y(y)$ then r.v.s are independent (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)